# Adding layers to chart embedded in rdlc report file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-applications, rdlc

I created a report file named (FullReport.rdlc), it contains chart control. 
what I want to do is to add textboxs and rectangle on the chart area, but it does not appear as i want it.

I'm using send to back/bring to front from visual studio bar, but it does not appear as a single unit, it appears after each other.

can anyone give me a solution to make this ?

I tried layers concept but i don't know how to make it with rdlc report file.